# Error in condition check inside add_custom_command of CMAKE

Tags: unit-testing, makefile, cmake, ctest, cmake-custom-command

I am trying to write *unit test* cases using **CMAKE** ctest .

I want to do unit test on my custom **add** and **inverse** function.

The difference between **add** and **inverse** test cases

1. **add** is using two inputs where as **inverse** is using single input
2. Address of the first input for both the test case is different

snippshort of my cmake file is showed below :

```
  add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT ${output_file_y} ${output_file_txt}
    COMMAND ${MY_EXECUTABLE}
    ARGS
     -lh ${bin_file} 0x10000000
     if((${function} STREQUAL "add"))
      -lh ${input_file0} 0x10100000
      -lh ${input_file1} 0x10200000 
     elseif((${function} STREQUAL "inverse"))
      -lh ${input_file0} 0x10c00000
     endif()
      ${options} 
     -outfile ${output_file_y}
     > ${output_file_txt}
    MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${bin_file}
    DEPENDS ${map_file} ${input_file0}
    COMMENT "Executing ${base_name_mangled}"
  )
```

After doing this I got below **Error**:

> /bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected ninja: build stopped:

> subcommand failed.

**Temporary Fixed:**

```
if((${function} STREQUAL "add"))      
      add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${output_file_y} ${output_file_txt}
        COMMAND ${MY_EXECUTABLE}
        ARGS
         -lh ${bin_file} 0x10000000
         -lh ${input_file0} 0x10100000
         -lh ${input_file1} 0x10200000 
          ${options} 
         -outfile ${output_file_y}
         > ${output_file_txt}
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${bin_file}
        DEPENDS ${map_file} ${input_file0}
        COMMENT "Executing ${base_name_mangled}"
      )
elseif((${function} STREQUAL "inverse"))
      add_custom_command(
        OUTPUT ${output_file_y} ${output_file_txt}
        COMMAND ${MY_EXECUTABLE}
        ARGS
         -lh ${bin_file} 0x10000000
         -lh ${input_file0} 0x10c00000
          ${options} 
         -outfile ${output_file_y}
         > ${output_file_txt}
        MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${bin_file}
        DEPENDS ${map_file} ${input_file0}
        COMMENT "Executing ${base_name_mangled}"
      )
endif()
```

But in temporary Fixed,it has more copy & paste code .I want to avoid this and combine both the add_custom_command together.

Is there any way to do so.

Comment: In CMake you cannot use commands inside other command's arguments. See the duplicate question about conditional command's arguments.

Comment: I have checked the link of earlier question which is answered. But my query is that can I use some thing like this outside add_custom_command command :    if((${function} STREQUAL "add"))
    set(INPUT_LIST       -lh ${input_file0} 0x10100000
      -lh ${input_file1} 0x10200000 )
   elseif((${function} STREQUAL "inverse"))
    set(INPUT_LIST       -lh ${input_file0} 0x10c00000))
   endif()

Comment: Yes, you may use this approach. It is described in the second snipped in the duplicate question (not in the answer to it!).